# COMODO antivirus : Getting message “Security agent could not be started” after uninstallation

Tags: windows-8.1, anti-virus, internet-security, runtime-error, comodo-firewall

I had COMODO antivirus installed in my Windows 8.1, 64 bit machine. I recently uninstalled it. But whenever I restart my machine it always prompts me this error message.

[image: Security agent could not be started]

Does it mean the uninstallation has not been successful and there are some components still  retain in my machine?

When I press "Yes" it prompts me another error message saying it is unable to load the resources.

[image: Error : loading resources]

How can I get rid of these errors at the start up? If any components of COMODO antivirus is still there in my machine how can I remove them completely?

Comment: Sounds like it didn't properly install.  I would reinstall it, then uninstall it again, if Comodo offers an cleaner program I would use that.

Comment: Did you try Comodo's uninstaller tool?...http://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-766-12685-.html

Comment: @Moab, no I didn't. I will try it and see if I can get rid of these messages.Thanks.

Comment: @Moab, thanks. I was able to detect and remove the existing components with this tool. I don't get these messages now.

Comment: You are Welcome @IsharaAmarasekera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by running "Comodo Uninstaller Tool" which you can download from [COMODO help page.](http://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-766-12685-.html)

It checks for uninstalled components and removes them from the computer.

Answer (score 0):

**comodo internet security could not be started

The room agent is giving an error message. It looks like the antivirus is disabled. In the desktop widget it appears as "risk" in red!
I uninstalled using Revouninstaller removing the leftovers and restarting. Still, it didn't work. My version of the Internet Security Room is from February 2019! Since yesterday he has the message:
"comodo internet security could not be started". I only solved it when I downloaded the uninstall tool here from the website, tool: http://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-766-12685-.html
Right after running it I had to restart my pc twice using this tool. So I downloaded the newest version of comodo internet security premium from the official Comodo website. I did the installation. Asked to restart the machine And the widget was still missing even with the comodo antivirus active. So I opened the antivirus and clicked on settings and checked "Display Widget on Desktop"! Within a minute the widget appeared.

My problem solved. Hope this helps!**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPpaz.png)